# parallel programming with parallel-invoke

Tags: concurrency

I want to use parallel programming to speed up the process.

In the class, there is a for loop in the member function, mainFun. In each iteration, subFun is called. How to use parallel-invoke to concurrently call subFun to fully-utilize the CPU power?

Thanks a lot.

The code is as follows:

```
#include <vector>
#include <ppl.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace concurrency;
typedef vector<double> Vector;
typedef vector<Vector> Matrix;

class myClass {
private:
    int num;
    Matrix a;

public:
    myClass(int n) :
        num(n), a(num, Vector(2)) {}

    Vector subFun(int n) {
        Vector b(2, 0);

        //body: to be implemented

        return b;
    }

    void mainFun() {
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {

            //parallel_invoke([&a[i]] { a[i] = subFun(i); });//<-- how to implement parallel_invoke?
        }
    }


};

int main() {

    myClass A(1000);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered multi-threading? You can invoke each function call in a separate thread.

Comment: Less than 50% of the CPU is used. As a result, I want to use parallel_invoke to make it faster.

Comment: if you have a thread pool with # of threads equal to number of cores?

Comment: I changed the code as:

parallel_invoke(
       [&] { a[i] = subFun(i); },
       [&] { a[i+num/4] = subFun(num/4+i); },
       [&] { a[i + 2*num / 4] = subFun(num / 4 + i); },
       [&] { a[i + 3*num / 4] = subFun(num / 4 + i); }
      );

How to use of for loop to make the code more compact?